# May I return a promise from a .then() callback?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a scenario where I need to create a task if it not exists, returning the task on both cases.

Is the following code correct?

```
CreateTaskIfNotExists(taskName: string): ng.IPromise<Task> {
     return this.GetTask(taskName)
        .then( t => {
            if (t) return t;
            else return this.CreateTask(taskName);
        });
}

CreateTask(taskName: string): ng.IPromise<Task> {
    // use $http to call Rest Web Service to create the task
    // and return promise
}

GetTask(taskName: string): ng.IPromise<Task> {
    // use $http to call Rest Web Service to getthe task
    // and return promise
}
```

The above code is in a service that I call from controller:

```
TaskService.CreateTaskIfNotExists(taskName)
    .then( task => {
         $scope.Task = task; 
    });
```

Will it work?

EDIT:

Just look at this piece of code:

```
    .then( t => {
        if (t) return t;
        else return CreateTask(taskName);
    });
```

`then` always returns a promise, a promise of the object returned in the callback. if `t` is something then returns `t`, therefore .`then` returns `ng.IPromise<Task>` right?. But if `t` is not something then returns `CreateTask(taskName)` which in turns returns a promise of type `ng.IPromise<Task>`, so what returns `then`? `ng.IPromise<ng.IPromise<Task>>`? or `then` unwraps it and returns `ng.IPromise<Task>` ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Create a task (or whatever) if it doesn't exist with the mínimum possible code. I can write it using $q.defer, but it requires more boilerplate code.

Comment: I'm simply asking if the following code is correct: if (t) return t; else return CreateTask(taskName); I return the object if it exists or return a promise that creates it.

Comment: Why not do the check in your controller?

so TaskService.GetTask(taskName).then( task => { if(task) {
 $scope.Task = task; 
} else {
  TaskService.CreateTask(taskName).then( task => {
 $scope.Task = task;
});
});

Comment: @Daniel Smink. Because it is the service responsability. And my code is cleaner.

Comment: Logic looks good, can't comment on syntax though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely you can return a promise in `.then` - this is how you execute consecutive async actions.

If you return a promise in `.then`, then when this promise is fulfilled the result will be given to the next chained `.then`.

If you return a (non-promise) value, then this is the value that will be given to the next chained `.then`.

The main thing is NOT to have an API that sometimes returns a promise and sometimes returns a value - but this is not what you have, so you are fine.

Here's an [illustrative example (plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ehCKeYYZDuIheRR7QQmp?p=preview)) similar to yours.